# Javascript " getParent() " not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to hide my parent `span` just above `<a>` tag and show the `span`  just below it.(When clicking it on the `<a>` tag).

I need to use getParent() because their are another same `<div>`s repeating

My HTML is

```html
<div class="Test">
  <p class="commentBody">
    <span class="view_more-comment">abcd...
      <a class="view_more_link" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$(this).getParent().getNext().style.display='';$(this).getParent().style.display='none';">more</a>
    </span>
    <span class="view_more" style="display: none;">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwzyz...
      <a class="view_less_link" onclick="$(this).getParent().getPrevious().style.display='';$(this).getParent().style.display='none';">less</a>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

When I use this `console` shows the error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).getParent is not a function

Any method to solve this problem?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no `getParent()` in `jQuery`. Use:

```
onclick="$(this).parent().prev().show(); $(this).parent().hide();"
```

[**Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

> Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

I'd recommend you to use **`on` for event handling** and not inline handlers

**EDIT**

Using jQuery:

```
$('.view_less_link').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.commentBody').find('.view_more-comment').show();
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Comment: @VP That is `Mootools` and not `jQuery`

Comment: Ohh. then how can i use it n my HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Use .parent() instead of getParent().

Answer (score 1):

Update your `html` as below and keep a similar class for both the links

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/j4jmkah7/1/)**

```
<span class="view_more-comment more">abcd...
     <a class="view_link " href="javascript:void(0);">more</a>
</span>
<span class="view_more less" style="display: none;">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwzyz...
     <a class="view_link" href="javascript:void(0);">less</a>
</span>
```

and then this JS

```
$('.view_link').on('click',function(){
   $(this).parent().slideToggle(200); 
   $(this).parent().siblings().slideToggle(200); 
});
```